# To Convert date column into 'dd/mm/yyyy' format without using to_char function

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, to-char

while selecting a date column in oracle, I want to Convert that date column into `dd/mm/yyyy` with out using a to_char function. Please suggest is there any way to get the required output.

My Date Format is `DD-MMM-YY` and I want to convert into `dd/mm/yyyy` without using to_char function

Comment: What data type is that column? A `date` column does not have "a format". Any format you _see_ is applied by whatever SQL client you are using.

Comment: Why the restriction of not using the right tool for the job? Is it a hacker's quiz or something?

Answer (score 0):

Of course, `TO_CHAR()` is simply the right tool for the job. But you can always change the session variable that controls the default output format and restore it later:

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD/MM/YYYY';
SELECT CAST(SYSDATE AS VARCHAR2(10 CHAR)) AS FORMATED_DATE
FROM DUAL;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT='DD-MON-YY';
```

The `CAST` bit is just a precaution against client tools handling the result as date and potentially changing format.